# jOOQ timeout on parallel execution doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, jooq

In short, I have the following queries:

```
fun find(request: Request): Result<Record> {
    val selectStep = dslContext
        .someFindLogic()
        .queryTimeout(QUERIES_TIMEOUT.toSeconds().toInt())

    return selectStep.fetch()
}

fun count(request: Request): Result<Record> {
    val selectStep = dslContext
        .someCountLogic()
        .queryTimeout(QUERIES_TIMEOUT.toSeconds().toInt())

    return selectStep.fetchCount()
}
```

with the following "async" exection:

```
val data = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { repository.find(request) }
val size = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync { repository.count(request) }

return SomeResponse(data.get(), size.get().toLong())
```

the problem is that, for some unkown reason, the second count query haven't ever been restricted by query timeout, and following some bad situations, it's keep executing:

[image: timeout is working for find, not working for count]

any ideas why it could happen?

Comment: jOOQ just passes the timeout value to the JDBC `Statement`, in case that helps troubleshooting.